# Why are my computers trying to connect to an (?)unassigned local IP address

Tags: networking, router, lan, zoom-meeting

I am seeing entries like the following in my router firewall log:

`Oct 02 17:03:30  [352898.020000] Firewall: Denied CONN=lan MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:08:00 SRC=aa.aaa.aaa.aa DST=192.168.0.131 LEN=113 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=9095 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=45046 DPT=58579 LEN=93 MARK=0x2`

`Oct 02 19:30:21  [361709.510000] Firewall: Denied CONN=lan MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:08:00 SRC=bb.bbb.bbb.bb DST=192.168.86.240 LEN=124 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=41607 PROTO=UDP SPT=56408 DPT=61485 LEN=104 MARK=0x2`

`XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` is the MAC address of my router. `YY:YY:YY:YY:YY` and `aa.aaa.aaa.aa` are the MAC address and LAN-side IP address respectively of a desktop running Ubuntu 20.04. `ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ` and `bb.bbb.bbb.bb` are the MAC address and LAN-side IP address respectively of a desktop running Windows 10.

Both computers are physically connected to the router via its LAN ports. The router is connected to a cable modem. The cable modem is connected to my ISP. The LAN-side IP address of my modem is `192.168.100.1`. I have multiple VLANs, but none use IP addresses starting with `192.168`. I am not aware of any devices connected to my router with the IP addresses `192.168.0.131` and `192.168.86.240`.

1. What are the `192.168.0.131` and `192.168.86.240` addresses and why are my computers attempting to connect to them (if that is what is happening here)?
2. Is this expected behavior or could this be a sign of something bad happening (misconfiguration, malware, etc.)?

Further details and some investigation:

The entries corresponding to the Ubuntu machine appear to always exactly coincide with the beginning of a Zoom call/meeting on that machine. In the last two instances, 133 and 284 connection attempts respectively were made in the span of a few seconds when a meeting started. No further connection attempts were made later during the meetings. Blocking these connections appeared to have no effect on Zoom functionality. Zoom is installed inside a VM (guest OS is also Ubuntu 20.04). The VM uses the host OS's internet connection.

I have not been able to figure out what triggers the connection attempts from the Windows machine. A burst of 25 connection attempts over a few seconds seems to occur about once a day.

This is my first question here, and I would appreciate any feedback on how to improve it.

Comment: try using Wireshark on the windows machine to record the network activity

Comment: Since you are blocking them, we cannot tell from the traffic what they are and a network dump will not help. The ports used are not what you would call well known and are all different, so that does not suggest some normal listening application. Therefore I would expect 2 possibilities. The first, given that it is a burst of 25 packets, someone has setup a periodic smokeping. The second is that it may be some old application, since removed, is looking for a server it used to access. In either case, it also looks like the IP addresses are historic and were used some time ago. Check for cron app

Comment: @Bib thank you for the feedback. I checked Task Scheduler on the Windows machine (I believe that's the equivalent of Cron that Windows uses?) and did not find entries that match the activity I'm seeing in terms of timing. I am not familiar with smokeping. If it is generating the traffic, would it have been set up on the machine from which the traffic is originating?

Comment: @jsotola Thank you. I will try to examine the traffic with Wireshark. Will update the question once I am able to do that.